# What should i do to make my program run faster?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a python program which processes a html page and creates a dictionary of urls as key and md5sum of the file as a value. The dictionary length is 6000. Each url is a zip file which is downloaded in to machine, each time checking md5sum after the file is downloaded. The total size of all the files that are to be downloaded is 572 GB.

The *URLs* is a dictionary which has download links as key and md5sum of file as value

The code is

```
        DownloadAllURLs(URLs)

        def DownloadAllURLs(URLs):
            for eachurl in URLs:
                if os.path.isfile(eachurl):
                     print eachurl, "already exists"
                else:
                     print "Going to Download",eachurl
                     Download(eachurl)
                     CheckMd5(eachurl,URLs(eachurl))

        def Download(eachurl):
            command='sudo wget --user=abc --password=xyz'
            command=command+" "+url
            print command
            result=subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            out, err=result.communicate()

        def CheckMd5(url,tail,md5sum):
            command=['md5sum',tail]
            result=subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            md5, err=result.communicate()
            if(md5[:32]==md5sum):
                print "The",tail,"is downloaded successufully with correct md5"
            else:
                print "The",tail,"is not downloaded correcty wrong md5"
               WriteWarcFile(url,tail)
               CheckMd5(url,tail,md5sum)
```

The above code downloads all the 6000 zip files for me, but the server from where i am downloading is very slow and i get only 40-60 kbps some times when downloading ..

I am using the above code to download like 1-3 terrabytes of data.... I want to parallelize my code in python (so the time taken to process will be reduced) but i am not sure whether to use multithreading or multiprocessing or anything else.

I am reading the tutorials but not sure how to proceed.  Thank you

**Edited:**

Thanks for all the replies, the main question i want to ask is how to apply multithreading/multithreading in cases like this. Suppose i am doing some operations on every URL rather than downloading it like the below code, can i make it any faster using multithreading or mutlprocessing

```
    from urlparse import urlparse
    ProcessAllURLs(URLs)
    def ProcessAllURLs(URLs):
        for eachurl in URLs:
                x=urlparse(eachurl)
                print eachurl.netloc
```

Comment: Downloading terabytes of data is bringing the server to its knees. Let's try hitting it with requests 5 times as fast!

Comment: @kich is your program too slow or is the server too slow?

Comment: I think server is being slow, sometimes it gives me 40kbps speed while otherwise it gives 26 mbps speed. I have no option rather than downloading from their server, so i am wondering if there is any way i can ping the server more times and download faster

Comment: @kich: pinging a server more times is how one slows down/crashes a server, it doesn't speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

As processing is IO-bound it should be possible to use python multithreading - global interpreter lock won't affect performance much